# salesforce dx pull error: No source format support for type Audience

Tags: salesforcedx

When I try to run `sfdx force:source:pull -f` in my scratch org, I got the following error:

> ERROR: No source format support for type Audience. Although the
>   Metadata Coverage report indicates the Metadata API supports source
>   format for this metadata type Audience, Salesforce CLI doesn’t

I am just wondering if there is way for me to retrieve everything exclude the audience?

Comment: Please accept the solution that works for the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this in Query editor:

```
SELECT Id, MemberType, MemberName FROM SourceMember WHERE MemberType = 'Audience'
```

and check **Use Tooling API**

Then delete record and you can do pull without -f force

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. It works.

Answer (score -1):

Create .forceignore file and add the audience metadata path there.

probably it will be

```
force-app/main/default/audience
```

Comment: audience doesn't work. That's actually one thing I am asking here, I am not sure about the folder name

Comment: Other workaround is to delete audience from sourcemember tooling object

Comment: Can I know how to follow that approach, please?

Comment: Execute a tooling query against the sourcemember object and delete audience row from it

Comment: I tried with that, I can't find audience as a memberName in that table. Thanks for that though